# end child gracefully when doing Ctrl-C in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, child-process, sigint

I have a architecture with one parent that spawns a child as follow :

```
this.process = child.spawn(this.cmd, this.args);

this.process.on('exit', (code: number, signal: string) => {
    this.exitCode = code;
    console.log(`exit code: ${code}`);
});
```

there is no particular option because i want to keep a link with the child. So, when i press Ctr-C to kill the parent, it catches `SIGINT` to (1) end the child, (2) exit properly. But `SIGINT` is also propagated to the child, so the parent cannot end it gracefully. So, is there a way to do so ? maybe by preventing `SIGINT` to be propagated to the child ? or telling the child to ignore the signal ?

i know that something is possible by adding option `detached: true` and `stdio: 'ignore'` when spawning, but i don't want to do that because if the parent dies, i end up with zombies process. Whereas keeping the links ensure that the child is killed if the parent dies unexpectedly. Finally, i want to avoid catching `SIGINT` in the child as i want to keep it dumb.

**EDIT:** the parent already have a `process.on('SIGINT', () => { ... }` and the child is in python.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch exit codes like this:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  // handle it yourself
})
```

You can propagate it to children like so:

```js
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  this.child.kill('SIGINT')
})
```

The child can of course also choose to handle the signal, it is wise to not assume the child process will exit simply because you sent a single signal. You may need to set a timeout and send repeat or different signals to fully kill a process. You will also want to listen to the `'exit'` message of the child process to know when its actually killed before continuing.

### Documentation

- [Process Signal Events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events)
- [Kill Sub-Process With Signal](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal)

Comment: the thing is that `SIGINT` is sent to the whole group. Which means to the child as well. I actually already have `process.on('SIGINT', () => { //end child }` but it does not prevent the child to receive `SIGINT` independently. Moreover, `spawn` function returns the child process. So, in the code a gave, if i add `this.process.on('SIGINT', () => { //do something }`, i would expect the `SIGINT` to be catch also for the child. but it is not the case. And it seems (through what a read), that the child need to be detached from the parents to work. Wich i don't want.

Comment: Like you suggested yourself, it seems you'll need to catch the signal from the child and handle it / ignore it there. I will be doing that in my case, where both parent and child are Node processes.